# How to efficiently unfold query results into a dictionary

Tags: python, mysql, list, python-3.x, dictionary

(I will state this is for learning purposes).
I have a query which returns `('a',) , ('b',) , ('c',)`
Which I translate to a dictionary which is `{a: '',b: '', c: ''}`
I am doing it the simple way:

```
    for(results) in MySQL_CLASS.cursor:
        MyDict[results[0]] = ''
```

Is there a shorter way to write this?

Comment: You could try using `dict.fromkeys`, but you're still doing to need to index the tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>>> results = (('a',) , ('b',) , ('c',))
>>> {x[0]: '' for x in results}
{'a': '', 'c': '', 'b': ''}
```

Comment: Btw, you can shorten it to `{x: '' for x, in results}`.

Comment: @alexce: Wouldn't that cause the keys yo be tuples? I get following: `>>> {x: '' for x in results}` -> `>>> {('c',): '', ('a',): '', ('b',): ''}`

Comment: Note the comma after the `x` - it unpacks the tuples.

Comment: Oh true, missed that in my experiment

Answer (score 0):

[Dict comprehension based approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37466142/771848) should be preferred, but, for educational purposes, here is an another option that involves using [`dict.fromkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) with `operator.itemgetter` and `map`:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> l = [('a',) , ('b',) , ('c',)]
>>> dict.fromkeys(map(itemgetter(0), l), '')
{'a': '', 'c': '', 'b': ''}
```